# Location of files written by spring-boot application on Google Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a Spring-boot application on Google cloud. This is a web application in which the JS client captures frames from the camera and sends it back to the server. The server processes these images and stores them in a directory. This application works perfectly fine locally and on the Google cloud. But on the cloud, I am not able to locate the directory created by the application. Could you please suggest a possible solution?

Comment: just to confirm you are using standard or flexible environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Google App Engine Environment, the local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. This behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application.

If your application needs to save and write files I suggest you take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage) where you can find different kind of solutions, for example, as per is mentioned at the document:

"App Engine creates a default bucket when you create an app. This bucket provides the first 5GB of storage for free and includes a free quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations. You can create other Cloud Storage buckets, but only the default bucket includes the first 5GB of storage for free."

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will try to make the necessary changes in the application.